# Canonical form of 2nd order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Say I have $$a(x,y)u_{xx} + 2b(x,y)u_{xy} + c(x,y)u_{yy} = f(x,y,u,u_x,u_y)$$ with characteristic equation $$a(x,y)\lambda^2 - 2b(x,y)\lambda +c(x,y)=0$$ with repeated root $\lambda = \frac{b(x,y)}{a(x,y)}$, so the characteristic slopes satisfy $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{a(x,y)}{b(x,y)}$ which has solution $\phi(x,y)=constant$. Then if I take $\psi(x,y)$ to be a linearly independent function and transform the PDE from $(x,y) \rightarrow (\phi,\psi)$ then I get $$A(\phi,\psi)u_{\phi\phi} + 2B(\phi,\psi)u_{\phi\psi} + C(\phi,\psi)u_{\psi\psi} = F(\phi,\psi,u,u_\phi,u_\psi)$$ with characteristic equation $$A(\phi,\psi)\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\psi}\right)^2 - 2B(\phi,\psi)\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\psi}\right) + C(\phi,\psi)=0$$ which has root $\frac{d\phi}{d\psi}=0$, but then this implies $C=0$. But I'm told that I should have $A=0$ and $C$ non-zero, so why do I get $C=0$?

Comment: Just realised it should be $C\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\psi}\right)^2 - 2B\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\psi}\right) + A=0$, that's why I got $C=0$ instead of $A=0$